# Getting values from nested NSDictionary in Order?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary

```
dictionary = (_NSDictionaryM) 3 key/value pairs
    [0] = @"CELL2" : 1 : key/value pair
        key = (__NSCFString) @"CELL2"
        value = (__NSDictionaryM) 1 key/value pair
            [0] = @"download" : @"Text Response"
                key = (__NSCFString) @"download"
                value = (__NSCFString) "Text Response"
    [1] = @"CELL1" : 1 : key/value pair
        key = (__NSCFString) @"CELL1"
        value = (__NSDictionaryM) 1 key/value pair
            [0] = @"download" : @"Text Response"
                key = (__NSCFString) @"download"
                value = (__NSCFString) "Text Response"
    [2] = @"CELL3" : 1 : key/value pair
        key = (__NSCFString) @"CELL3"
        value = (__NSDictionaryM) 1 key/value pair
            [0] = @"download" : @"Text Response"
                key = (__NSCFString) @"download"
                value = (__NSCFString) "Text Response"
```

I have a dictionary that looks like above. Using fast enumeration, I can get the "Text Responses" (which is what I ultimately want, I don't care about anything else). The issue is that I need to also get them in order when I store them into an array. The order I do get them in is consistent per dictionary (I'll always get them in `2, 1, 3,` for example), but different for each dictionary I'm going through.

Additional info: 
`dictionary` can have an arbitrary number of entries, but the inside of it is always the same, and I must pull the data out of a dictionary, it cannot be delivered to me in any other way.

The attempts I've tried end up with the same result I have currently (I get the `text response` but out of order) or it will throw a exception because I'm performing an action on something that doesn't respond to it.

Comment: NSDictionary entries have no defined order.  There's no guarantee that even accessing the same dictionary twice will produce the same order both times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fast enumeration pulls dictionary keys in implementation-defined order (specifically, in the order consistent with hash codes of that dictionary's keys). If you need to enforce a specific order, pull the keys out of the dictionary into `NSArray`, sort that array to your liking, and then fast-iterate the array, pulling values from the dictionary for each key in the sorted order:

```
NSDictionary *dict = ...
// You can use any of the sortedArrayUsingXYZ methods below
NSArray *sortedKeys = [[dict allKeys] sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:...];
for (NSString *key in sortedKeys) {
    id obj = [dict getObjectForKey:key];
    ...
}
```

Comment: Worked great! Had to do a little more configuring to get what I wanted but I never expected you to solve it for me.